# "ReadProcessMemory" how to get std::string?

Tags: c++, process, console

Programm_A

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Process ID = " << GetCurrentProcessId() << "\n"; // Id my process (i get something like '37567')
    std::string My_String = "JoJo"; // My string
    std::cout << &My_String << std::endl; //here i get something like '0x0037ab7'
    system("pause");
}
```

This program just outputs reference of string "JoJo" to console.

Programm_B

```
int main()
{
    int id;
    std::cin >> id;
    DWORD ProcessId = id;
    HANDLE ProcessHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, ProcessId);
    if (!ProcessHandle) { 
        std::cout << "Process is not found...\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::string r;
    std::cin >> r; // this is me writing the link that I get in programs_A
    DWORD address = std::strtoul(r.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    std::string JoJo_string = " ";
    ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, (LPVOID)(address), &JoJo_string, sizeof(JoJo_string), 0); //here I want to get the JoJo_string value by reference from programm_A
    std::cout << JoJo_string << std::endl;
}
```

The funny thing is that everything works fine with the "int" variable type. But `std::string` is not working. The exact value reads, but the program immediately gives an error:

[-- [programm_B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCXUp.png) --]

[-- [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyVrb.png) --]

Comment: Knowing what actually resides at the address of a `std::string` object, as opposed to something like a native `int`, would be highly illuminating. Blasting over the memory backdrop of a non-trivial object like `std::string`, which contains internal pointers, references, etc., is *not* going to end well in any context, be it using something like `ReadProcessMemory`, `fread`, `memcpy`, or anything else in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *easily* read a `std::string` across process boundaries.

Different standard library implementations of `std::string` use different memory layouts for its data members. The `std::string` in your program may be using a different implementation than the program you are trying to read from.

But even if the two programs used the exact same implementation, it still wouldn't matter, because `std::string` is simply too complex to read with a single `ReadProcessMemory()` call. `std::string` uses dynamic memory for its character data, so one of its data members is a `char*` pointer to the data *stored elsewhere in memory*. Which is complicated by the fact that `std::string` might also implement a local Short-String Optimization buffer so short string values are stored directly in the `std::string` object itself to avoid dynamic memory allocations.

So, you would have to know the exact implementation of `std::string` being used by the target program in order to decipher its data members to discover where the character data is actually being stored, and in the case where SSO is not active then read the `char*` pointer, as well as the number of characters being pointed at (which itself is also determinate in an implementation-specific way), so you could then read the character data with another `ReadProcessMemory()` call.

In short, what you are attempting to do is a futile effort.

Answer (score -1):

You most certainly *CAN* get a content of the `std::string` from another process. After all, the debuggers do that!

You need to execute `data()` and `length()` functions of that string and then read content of that memory. The important point is to halt execution of the second process while you are doing that, or that memory location can become invalid between your calls.

Comment: You cannot. The layout of a `std::string` is an implementation detail that you cannot discover. A debugger relies on the compiler to emit those descriptions by way of a machine-readable PDB file. Your proposed solution fails to answer two vital questions: `1` How do you find the member functions? How do you find them when they were inlined? `2` How do you determine the point in time when it's safe to suspend the target process? Your proposition is relying on class invariants. How do you know that those aren't (temporarily) violated when you're looking?